# How to merge duplicate entries in a CSV import (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, multidimensional-array, import

I have been working on a project requiring me to import a csv file containing data on a large set of books (i.e. Title, Author, Genre/s) into a database. However, within the CSV there are duplicate rows for books, and these duplicates contain required information for each book entry. For example, one row may contain the book title, author and year, and another may contain the book title and genres.

So far I have read in the data, set variables for each column and added them to an array. However, I am having trouble as to how I should merge the arrays where there are two rows for a book, ensuring that all books have the required data. I have attempted using array_merge and array_replace both of which have been unsuccessful.

I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this problem?

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

    foreach ($row as $record) {

        $title = $row[0];
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title);

        $genre = $row[1];
        $genre = explode(",", $genre);

        $author = $row[2];
        $author = explode(",", $author);

        $year = $row[3];
        $year = intval($year);

        $books = array(
            "title" => $title,
            "genres" => $genre,
            "author" => $author,
            "year" => $year
        );
    }
```

Comment: First of all you need to define what's your primary key to understand two books are the same. Is it just the title? Or title+author? Or do you have a bookID somewhere that we don't see in your code?

Comment: Once you have identified your key, set that as `PRIMARY KEY` in your Mysql table. Instead of a simple Insert, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). This allows the first record to being inserted, and subsequent records to update the other columns

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the response. Yes, I have a book table which has an auto-incremented bookID, this table also stores the book title, author and year. Then I have a Genre table as there is a many to many relationship between books and genres, with a junction table between these two tables (BookGenre).